# Connector not showing up in AnyPoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I'm extremely new to Mule.

I just installed the Apple Push Notifications Connector from AnyPoint exchange and restarted AnyPoint Studio. The problem is the connector is not showing up for the project. I went back to the Exchange and it shows as "Installed".

Do any additional steps need to be taken to get connectors installed this way to appear in projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this namespaces and then build your flow inside.

```
    <mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:apple-push="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apple-push"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core
               http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
               http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apple-push
               http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apple-push/current/mule-apple-push.xsd">

      <!-- here goes your flows and configuration elements -->
</mule>
```

More info: [Connector Documentation](http://mulesoft.github.io/apple-push-connector/mule/apple-push.html)

Answer (score 0):

Does it appear in the palette? you can see the installed plugins in Help -> Installation Details, search for the connector and let me know if appears in there, it should be available for drag and drop after the restart.

Comment: No it doesn't show in the canvas even though does show as installed. I would also imagine it should show as drag and drop, but no such luck. Could it be the case that some connectors don't have UI (palette) support?

Comment: nope, devkit based connectors, like this one, have UI. You possibly installed something wrong, try uninstalling the connector and download it again.

Are you using the lastest Aanypoint Studio version?

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times. Still no luck. Using APS 5.2.0 and upgraded everything.

Comment: Having the same issue when creating a connector using a NestedProcessor... Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the connector shows up in the list of deprecated connectors. Go to Preferences > AnyPoint Studio > Palette Profiles. On the right side, select the runtime/s and check the box labelled 'Show deprecated Mule components and attributes'.